# Pytorch: Weight in cross entropy loss

Tags: python, pytorch, cross-entropy

I was trying to understand how weight is in CrossEntropyLoss works by a practical example. So I first run as standard PyTorch code and then manually both. But the losses are not the same.

```
from torch import nn
import torch
softmax=nn.Softmax()
sc=torch.tensor([0.4,0.36])
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=sc)
input = torch.tensor([[3.0,4.0],[6.0,9.0]])
target = torch.tensor([1,0])
output = loss(input, target)
print(output)
>>1.7529
```

Now for manual Calculation, first softmax the input:

```
print(softmax(input))
>>
tensor([[0.2689, 0.7311],
        [0.0474, 0.9526]])
```

and then negetive log of the correct class probality and multiply with the respective weight:

```
((-math.log(0.7311)*0.36) - (math.log(0.0474)*0.4))/2
>>
0.6662
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 16):

To compute class weight of your classes use `sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight(class_weight, *, classes, y)` [read it here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html)
This will return you an array i.e  `weight`.
eg .

```
x = torch.randn(20, 5) 
y = torch.randint(0, 5, (20,)) # classes
class_weights=class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',np.unique(y),y.numpy())
class_weights=torch.tensor(class_weights,dtype=torch.float)
 
print(class_weights) #([1.0000, 1.0000, 4.0000, 1.0000, 0.5714])
```

Then pass it to `nn.CrossEntropyLoss`'s weight variable

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights,reduction='mean')

loss = criterion(...)
```

Comment: should `np.unique(y)` be ordered ascendingly?

Comment: Those will be your number of classes; yes by default it will be ascending order

Comment: Shouldn't you pass `1/class_weights`? After all you want to increase the weight for minority classes.

Comment: Code returns error "compute_class_weight() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given"

Comment: @IsaacZhao you need to pass arguments implicitly `compute_class_weight('balanced', classes=np.unique(y), y=y.numpy())`

Comment: @AlaaM. `sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight` actually calculates inverse frequency as you expected: `len(y) / np.bincount(y)` -- so minority class gets a higher weight

Comment: @tozCSS - You are right! (but to be accurate, they further normalize by `n_classes` (number of classes))

Answer (score 7):

For any weighted loss `(reduction='mean')`, the loss will be normalized by the sum of the weights. So in this case:

```
((-math.log(0.7311)*0.36) - (math.log(0.0474)*0.4))/(.4+.36)
>> 1.7531671457872036
```